# Google actions webhook Failed to deploy cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, webhooks, actions-on-google

I am creating a google action and I am trying to connect with facts about google webhook.
https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-facts-about-google-nodejs/blob/master/sdk/webhooks/ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment/index.js

but clicking on 'deploy fulfilment', I am getting error "Failed to deploy cloud function.".
There is nothing in firebase logs.

[image]

Comment: I see the source code but to understand better, how are you creating a google action and how are you trying to connect with the facts. What is the complete error message? Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: I have added screenshot. Error message is not helpful and logs also don't have anything. Maybe some permission problem I am not sure.

Comment: The screenshot does not help in understanding what your code is and why the deployment has failed. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I have already added link of the code it's same "facts about google"

Comment: To narrow down the focus, I would suggest to deploy the function locally and see what happens. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: Toying around with Actions SDK recently, I discovered that the Cloud Build service is required but not enabled by default when you create projects in the console. Can you browse to the following link for your project, enable the Cloud Build and try to deploy again? https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudbuild.googleapis.com Alternatively, if you use the command-line: `gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com --project=${PROJECT}` where `PROJECT` is set to the project's ID.